# How is omniauth secure when used for Single Sign On?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, omniauth

I have been using omniauth, based off of tutorials similar to this: https://coderwall.com/p/bsfitw#

In this tutorial, and many others, you are instructed to find a user matching what you get back from omniauth, usually like so

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

So... what is to stop someone else from just posting :provider => "twitter", :uid => "Someone elses uid" to log in as them?

Answer (score 0):

So after talking to a couple people, it appears the reason is because the omniauth.auth variables are passed via environment variables set by the omniauth middleware, not passed in directly from the request.